# Concat strings into @declare

Tags: sql-server, ssms, where-clause, concatenation

I have `FirstName` and `LastName` from an employee table that has an employee ID. 
I want to pass the concatenated `firstName` and `lastname` in a where clause but instead of P.lastname and P.Firstname I want to pass it as where Name = 'Chand Reginald'

What I am trying to do is declare a named variable and have users enter the name which will return results.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[ETCInfo] @Date datetime, @Principal varchar(60), 

SELECT
P.LastName+' '+P.FirstName as 'PrincipalName'

where 1=1  AND rpTask.OutlineLevel < 12  AND P.LastName = 'Maguire' AND 
P.FirstName = 'Daryl' AND RPTask.WBS1 <> '<none>' AND 
rpPL.endDate>=dateadd(d,1,@Date)
```

I want the `@Principal` to be a concatenated value e.g. 'Maguire Daryl'

Comment: Please show us what you have tried as its hard to understand what you have written.

Comment: You mean `where P.LastName + ' ' + P.FirstName = @Principal`?

Comment: user will enter name like Reg Chand which  =  to @Principal which equals to P.firstName, ' ',P.LastName

Comment: So in that case try my comment as I believe it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this condition `P.LastName = 'Maguire' AND P.FirstName = 'Daryl'`, You should change to

```
P.LastName + ' ' + P.FirstName = @Principal -- or 'Maguire Daryl' as you wish.
```